# java вывод double

Tags: java, double

Почему такое выражение - System.out.println(468654654d / 15)-  выводиться в экспоненциальной форме - (3.12436436E7), а не в классической - 31243643.6 , какая зависимость ?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в методе `toString()` по умолчанию для `double` он определён [так](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double))

Если хотите этого избежать, пишите `System.out.printf("%.0f\n", 468654654d / 15);`