# При перемножении double вместо нулей пишется E

Tags: java, float, double

Делаю небольшой калькулятор, и при тестировании заметил, что, например, при перемножении 5000 и 5000, получаю не 25.000.000, а 2.5E7. Фактически, это одно и то же, но почему при перемножении относительно небольших чисел типа double получаю E, а при перемножении этих же чисел типа int получаю числа без E в результате?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [java вывод double](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739528/java-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-double)

Comment: Разместите код, с помощью которого вы это делаете.